# Android JSON parsing 'data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray' error

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm parsing this JSON on android -

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/s180x540/34325347_936407749733967_1354847545689012266_n.jpg?oh=dde033205b1230568dc26b7b01cy5424&oe=56599FD6"
  }
}
```

I have this code -

```
                        json = response.getJSONObject();
                        Log.d("json data",json.toString());

                        try {

                            jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

that gives this error - **data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray**

Can anyone tell what wrong is there ? Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Also post your JSON returned data. It seems like "data" is not array.

Comment: You get perhaps a JSONObject and inside your JSONArray, it's better to post your Json data.

Comment: i just updated the question with the JSON

Comment: data is not a jsonArray , it is a jsonObject

Comment: How should the correction be made in the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON Array start with `[` and end with `]`   :
[image]

and JSON Object start with `{` and end with `}`   :
[image]

So you need to get JSONObject not JSONArray.
`getJSONObject("data")`

Answer (score 2):

The data instance isn't an array, but a JSON object.
Therefore `getJSONArray` throws the exception. Use `getJSONObject("data")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here on examples of JSON data types:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

You are working with object, not array. Arrays are rounded with '[' and ']'.

Answer (score 1):

As "data" is a JsonObject and you are trying to access it as JsonArray you are facing this exception instead try this:

```
json = response.getJSONObject();
Log.d("json data",json.toString());

try {
    JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONObject("data");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no JSON array in your json.
Use following code

```
String jsonString = "{
  'data': {
    'is_silhouette': false,
    'url': 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/s180x540/34325347_936407749733967_1354847545689012266_n.jpg?oh=dde033205b1230568dc26b7b01cy5424&oe=56599FD6'
  }
}";
JSONObject jsonObj =  new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject data  =  jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
String url = data.getString("url");
```